# How do draw italic text on Android canvas?

Tags: android, text, android-canvas, italic

In my app I am drawing text on Android `Canvas`;

Now to support `underline` and `bold` I am taking help of paint object;

```
 Paint paint = new Paint();   

 paint.setUnderlineText(true); 
 paint.setFakeBoldText(true);

 paint.setColor(color);
 paint.setTextSize (font_size);
 canvas_obj.drawText(text,x,y,paint);
```

With this code I am getting bold and underlined text;

I also like to make it `italic`,

I am developing app for android 2.2 onwards.

how to do it?

**Edit:**

I am setting Typeface object created with an external font file to support external font; For Italic I am using following code

```
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(external_font_type_face,Typeface.ITALIC));
```

This also not working,
Tested on Samsung Galaxy Ace (android 2.2)

Answer (score 30):

You can use that method :

```
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.ITALIC));
```

It's working for me.

Comment: I am already using a Typeface object( created with an external font file, ) in paint ; I am developing app for android 2.2 onwards

Comment: @Swarnendu Typeface has been implemented in Android 1.5

Comment: @ Ty221   Unfortunately it is not working, setting typeface to paint object is replacing previously set typrface object to the paint object(which was set to support external font  ); so neither I am getting the external font support nor italic text with default font.. :-(

Comment: I don't know other way (Google also don't know)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.